# Return unknown length array from c to Swift in structure

Tags: c++, c, memory, swift

I am working on bridging between a C++ class and Swift. I know I can only interface with c and Objective C so I am writing a wrapping function in c.

I need to return some data that I have packaged in a structure and with the structure holding an array of unknown length. All this needs to be done with only c to interface with Swift.

My structure looks as follows:

```
 struct Output {
      double DataA;
      long DataArrayLength;
      double *DataArray;
 };
```

I have written the following function in c to package the data:

```
 struct Output* GetData( double InputA) {
      struct Output output;
      output.DataArrayLength = 100; // The length will only be known at run time and
                                    // once I get into this function.
      output.DataArray = new double[output.DataArrayLength];
      ///
        Fill in the data array - some complicated calculations behind this.
        output.DataArray[0] = 12345.0;
        output.DataArray[99] = 98761.0;
      ///
      return &output;  // Getting warning Address of stack associated with local variable 'output' returned.
 }
```

From Swift I can then call

```
 var swoutput = GetData( 1.0)
 var count = swoutput.memory.DataArrayLength
```

My questions are:

Is there a better way do do this? How?

How should I allocate, pass, return the Output struct? I realize the problem with the current method but not sure the best fix.

I still need to release the memory from DataArray. I think I need to do this from the Swift code. How do I do this?

Comment: `struct Output output;` is defined in the scope of `struct Output* GetData( double InputA)` function. `output` will have no existence once the function call returns. so returning `&output` is wrong. You can try using pointers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do:

```
Output* GetData( double InputA) {
    Output* output = new Output;
    output->DataArrayLength = 100; // The length will only be known at run time and
                                   // once I get into this function.
    output->DataArray = new double[output->DataArrayLength];
    /// Fill in the data array - some complicated calculations behind this.
    output->DataArray[0] = 12345.0;
    output->DataArray[99] = 98761.0;
    ///
    return output;
 }
```

And don't forget:

```
void DeleteOutput(Output* output)
{
    if (output == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    delete [] output->DataArray;
    delete output;
}
```